# I am trying to include two Models in my index page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

i am trying to add the "Cars" and "Customers" model into my homepage to create a search function which once clicked sends to a different page which has a table of the cars and customers which match against the search criteria.

I made a view model class with all the fields i wanted in the class

```
 public class HomeViewModel

{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; } // Customer

    public string LicenseNo { get; set; }//Customer

    public int CustomerID { get; set; } //Customer

    public int CarID { get; set; } //Car

    public string Make { get; set; } // Car

    public string Model { get; set; } // Car

    public string RegNumber { get; set; } //Car

    public string Colour { get; set; } //Car

    public int CarCategoryID { get; set; } //Car Category

    public string CarCategoryName { get; set; } //Car Category
}
```

Then in my HomeController I added the following

```
public ActionResult Index(string Search)
    {
        ViewBag.asad = Search;
        List<HomeViewModel> homeViewModels = new List<HomeViewModel>(); // to hold list of Customer and order details

        var customerlist = (from Cust in db.Customers

                            join Ord in db.Cars on Cust.CustomerID equals Ord.CarID
                            select new
                            {
                                Cust.CustomerName,
                                Cust.CustomerID,
                                Cust.LicenseNo,
                                Ord.CarID,
                                Ord.Make,
                                Ord.Model,
                                Ord.RegNumber,
                                Ord.Colour,
                                Ord.CarCategoryID,
                                Ord.CarCategory.CarCategoryName,

                            }).ToList();

        //query getting data from database from joining two tables and storing data in customerlist

        foreach (var item in customerlist)

        {
            HomeViewModel objcvm = new HomeViewModel(); // ViewModel

            objcvm.CustomerID = item.CustomerID;
            objcvm.CustomerName = item.CustomerName;
            objcvm.LicenseNo = item.LicenseNo;
            objcvm.CarID = item.CarID;
            objcvm.Make = item.Make;
            objcvm.Model = item.Model;
            objcvm.RegNumber = item.RegNumber;
            objcvm.Colour = item.Colour;
            objcvm.CarCategoryID = item.CarCategoryID;
            objcvm.CarCategoryName = item.CarCategoryName;

            homeViewModels.Add(objcvm); //Using foreach loop fill data from custmerlist to List<CustomerVM>.
        }
            return View(homeViewModels); //List of HVM (ViewModel)
```

This code is not returning `null` but its returning `count=0` but i do have data in the fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core will never return `null` because you already initialized the list `homeViewModels` at very beginning.

Now if the count=0 in model means your `customerlist` is also empty. Which is coming from the Database so I think there are no matching records found or the joining condition is wrong.

You are joining the Car's `CarID` with Customer's `CustomerID` which looks wrong.

Comment: So how should i fix it??